Android Instant App: download on-demands modules failed
I'm using Unity Engine to build an Instant Game. Because the app size is over 20MB, so I split the assets into on-demands modules for download when the game start.
I'm using Instant App, Android App Bundle and Play Asset Delivery plugin to config and build .aab file.
The instant game is uploaded on Google Play Internal Test, it run fine, but when try downloading asset pack, it only failed with error code -15 (AssetPackErrorCode.UNRECOGNIZED_INSTALLATION).
I tested instant app in local (with Build And Run command), it still failed with error code -15 too.
I've tested the same with install game. The game start and downloading the assets successful without any error.
How i can fix this problem?
